# Should you remove migration files in Laravel to cleanup a project

Tags: laravel, database, migration

My project has some migration files which are now migrated and its all good. But if I want to clean up my project, I was thinking about deleting all the migration files because they are already set

My project is a Laravel project.

Do you suggest removing the ones like 'create_vacancies' ? Because its already migrated and there is nothing left to do with this file right?

I do NOT want to remove migrations on the database, just the files that once created them.
Its for cleaning up the project.

I just need some advice on if I can remove these migrated files

Comment: what if you have to deploy it to another server or you want someone else to run the project, etc etc? migrations are version control for your schema ... you could squash them into a single sql file as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer**

> I just need some advice on if I can remove these migrated files

Yes you can, your application will continue to work fine even if they are deleted if they are already migrated in production. It's not recommended to delete them, but for most people, deleting them won't cause that much harm either. Even in the worst-case scenarios, there are tools that can generate Laravel migration files by scanning the database so there's still some way out. But keep in mind that not having migration files will cause some inconveniences in local development. Continue reading for more info

**Longer Answer**

In General, it is recommended **not to delete your migration files**, they are usually still useful even after you've migrated them. Some of the scenarios where they are still useful are

1. Some day in the future, you decide that you want a fresh database to test out something. If you have the migrations, all you need is to run `php artisan migrate:fresh` to get a fresh database, it will drop all tables and create them fresh. This will be a lot more convenient than truncating each table
2. Having the migrations will help you rollback them. Although chances of needing this is low, depending on the way you develop, it could be useful. I personally use `php artisan migrate:rollback` a lot during development to test out various scenarios to ensure everything will work well when it goes to production
3. Migrations help you get a quick view of which datatype your columns are. Although there are better ways to check this, the quickest is usually the migrations as long as there are not a lot of alter table migrations
4. Having the migrations will help you write better unit/functional tests since you can easily spin up a test database quickly by running `php artisan migrate`. Laravel supports this feature by adding the `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations` trait to your tests ( note this does have performance impact )

If having a lot of unused migration files starts getting annoying, you could also run the following command to squash all the migrations ( Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#squashing-migrations )

```bash
# Dump the current database schema and prune all existing migrations...
php artisan schema:dump --prune
```